# Java 21 upgrade with Embedded Flapdoodle Mongo db failing at gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, java-21, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

Upgrading one of our service to Java 21 and Spring boot 3.1.5. Service contains Embedded Mongo db and has been updated as below.

```
<dependency> 
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId> 
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring30x</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version> 
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However, All the unit and integration tests are getting executed without any issues in local but failing in gitlab runner.

How do we resolve this error?.

Below is the error message for the same.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
    'syncClientServerWrapper' defined in class path resource 

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not start process at 
    de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.transitions.MongoServerStarter.result(MongoServerStarter.java:129) 
    at de.flapdoodle.reverse.TransitionWalker.resolve(TransitionWalker.java:58) 
    at de.flapdoodle.reverse.TransitionWalker.resolve(TransitionWalker.java:46) 
    at de.flapdoodle.reverse.TransitionWalker.initState(TransitionWalker.java:180) 
    ... 102 common frames omitted 
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program  
    "/root/.embedmongo/fileSets
    /4b177cbd88668a95edf49714fa2964a4a940f94feb0f2b0e279810a865d7d313/mongod" 
    (in directory "/tmp/temp--033a8268-15b0-4a18-b06b-1f5a6901c65f/
     workingDir1858686435819966950"): error=2, No such file or directory 
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1170) 
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089) 
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.ProcessControl.start(ProcessControl.java:177) 
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.types.RunningProcess.start(RunningProcess.java:76) 
    at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.transitions.MongoServerStarter.result(MongoServerStart
```

Tried various ways to resolve this but not able to solve this problem. Because of this we need to downgrade to Java 17.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the image you are using for your runner is not compatible with embedded mongo. In my case, I was using an apline image for gradle, which was causing issues. Switching to using an non apline image i.e gradle:jdk-11 was able to resolve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).